# want to make table in flex4 like Microsoft word 2007?

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

i want to make a table like word 2007 table in flex4 using action script3 and mxml.
Any good suggestion or like example help me.
thanks in advance!!!![image]

Comment: can you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a flex mx:Grid (I've been in 3.5 so long, I'm not sure if there's a spark equivalent).

```
<mx:Grid>
  <mx:GridRow>
    <mx:GridItem>
      //component here (Label?)
    </mx:GridItem>
    <mx:GridItem/>
    <mx:GridItem/>
    <mx:GridItem/>
  </mx:GridRow>
  <mx:GridRow>
    <mx:GridItem/>
    <mx:GridItem/>
    <mx:GridItem/>
    <mx:GridItem/>
  </mx:GridRow>
  <mx:GridRow>
    <mx:GridItem/>
    <mx:GridItem/>
    <mx:GridItem/>
    <mx:GridItem/>
  </mx:GridRow>
</mx:Grid>
```

The base grid will not have borders though, that's got to be done in CSS. I use some that looks like this, in one application.

```
.gridItem {
        border-color: #F5F5F5;
        border-style: solid;
        border-thickness: 2;
        padding-bottom: 8;
        padding-top: 8;
        padding-right: 8;
        padding-left: 8;
    }
```